# Determine how library or feature was loaded

Tags: emacs, package, startup, delayed-execution

How can I determine where the load point is for an emacs library? For example, I'm trying to track down and remove any runtime `require`s of `subr-x` during initialization, so I'd like to know which library loaded it.

The `load-history` lists loaded files along with the `require`s they made *when* they were loaded, but doesn't seem to provide information about any `require`s that weren't evaluated initially, but may have been later.

As a simple example, if I <kbd>M-x</kbd>`load-file` "/path/to/the/following/test.el"

```
(defun my-f ()
  (require 'misc))

(provide 'my-test)
```

I see the first entry in `load-history` is

```
("/path/to/test.el"
  (defun . my-f)
  (provide . my-test))
```

Then, evaluating `(my-f)`, adds an entry for "misc.el", but there is no indication where it was loaded from (neither is the above entry updated).

How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I determine where the load point is for an emacs library?

You can't. There are many reasons an Emacs library will be loaded, for example,

- autoload
- C-x C-e some lisp code
- M-: some lisp code
- M-x load-library

> For example, I'm trying to track down and remove any runtime requires of subr-x during initialization, so I'd like to know which library loaded it.

Use `C-h v load-history`, the order is meaningful, for example, your init file loads foo.el, and foo.el requires bar.el, then bar.el requires subr-x.el, `load-history` should looks like

```
(foo.el bar.el subr-x.el)
```

It's not an elegant solution, but worked for me.

Comment: thanks, yea this was my original approach-- searching through the load-history

Comment: however, this answer isn't correct, since it is possible to determine in all of cases AFAICT

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, that *seems* works fine for my purposes, I ended up "watching" for an initial call by `load` or `require` to a specific library.  It's easy to get the name of the file where the `require`/`load` took place when an actual load is in progress and `load-file-name` is defined.

I was less interested in other cases, eg. interactive evaluation, but the following still works -- at least after very minimal testing, it just dumps a backtrace instead of the filename. From the backtrace, it's not hard to find the calling function, and if desired, the calling function's file could presumably be found with `symbol-file`.

Running the following locates loads/requires of `subr-x`, reporting in the message buffer the filenames of packages where it was loaded and dumping backtraces around deferred loading locations.

> emacs -q -l /path/to/this.el -f find-initial-load

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar path-to-init-file "~/.emacs.d/init.elc")

(defun find-load-point (lib &optional continue)
  "During the first `require' or `load', print `load-file-name' when defined.
Otherwise, dump a backtrace around the loading call.
If CONTINUE is non-nil, don't stop after first load."
  (let* ((lib-sym (intern lib))
         (lib-path (or (locate-library lib) lib))
         (load-syms (mapcar
                     (lambda (s)
                       (cons s (intern (format "%s@watch-%s" s lib-sym))))
                     '(require load)))
         (cleanup (unless continue
                    (cl-loop for (ls . n) in load-syms
                       collect `(advice-remove ',ls ',n)))))
    (pcase-dolist (`(,load-sym . ,name) load-syms)
      (advice-add
       load-sym :around
       (defalias `,name
         `(lambda (f sym &rest args)
            (when (or (equal sym ',lib-sym)
                      (and (stringp sym)
                           (or (string= sym ,lib)
                               (file-equal-p sym ',lib-path))))
              ,@cleanup
              (prin1 (or (and load-in-progress
                              (format "%s => %s" ',lib-sym load-file-name))
                         (backtrace))))
            (apply f sym args)))))))

(defun find-initial-load ()
  "Call with 'emacs -q -l /this/file.el -f find-initial-load'."
  (find-load-point "subr-x" 'continue)
  (load path-to-init-file))

;; test that deferred requires still get reported
(defun my-f () (require 'subr-x))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'my-f)
```

Comment: No need for an advice: you can hook into `after-load-functions`.

Comment: @Stefan that looks promising. I'd be interested in who's loading the file, not the actual file -- any recommendations on how to get that info?

Comment: IIUC you mostly need that for debugging purposes, so I'd just call `debug` which will show you a backtrace which should provide all the info you need.  If you need it for other purposes than debugging the name of the actual file from which the load happened is not so readily available, no.

Comment: yup, it was for debugging type stuff originally, but it spawned some new ideas.  Did you ever consider adding a method/macro for "one-off" advices like this (run once and destory themselves) in nadvice? I find myself using them now and again